# dosbox error in tasm as illegal command

Tags: dosbox

whenevevr I m using dosbox emmulator and after mounting i m writing tasm or td tasm edit tasm then it is showing error "illegal command tasm" or illegal command edit

Comment: Edit your question to include more context and details. You should provide an example of what you are trying to do, tell us the exact steps needed to reproduce the problem and copy/paste the entire error.  Please use formatting and [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) so that we can distinguish commands and output from the surrounding text. As the question is currently written, details are too ambiguous and deficient to understand.

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to Ubuntu. In fact it's about MS-DOS and in this case specially DOS-Box. Seems you didn't mount your tools location properly and/or running them from a wrong location or without setting up your path variable.
The error "illegal command" in dos-box is equivalent for "bad command or file name" in real ms-dos environment.
As a first step make sure you have Turbo Assembler/Debugger downloaded on your PC. Then after running DOS-Box mount your tools location using [mount](https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/MOUNT) command
Finally change current drive using drive letter of mounted drive (for example c: ). Now you can run your tools (td / tasm /...) the same way as MS-DOS